# begin{align} behaving oddly - Lines after (10) show up as exponents

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

I'll let the picture speak for itself.

[image]

It's probably a silly mistake but I have been awake for the past 20 or so hours and in my current state I can't, for the life of me, find the mistake that causes this.

Any pointers for a dumbfounded Greek?

Comment: It would be better if you made a complete, minimal code example, and included the code in your question. Doing so and you may find the silly mistake yourself, and if not it makes it easier for those answering the question when there is a compilable code example included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not the lines are as exponents, but numbers of lines are below. It is because lines are too long to leave space for two-cipher numbers. They are as long, as the longest one. Your usage of `align` is, well, nonstandard. An ordinary usage is

```
(first part) & (second part) \\
```

Hence dividing 9th line in a manner

```
&(implication)\\
& \qquad (the Greek text)\\
```

should solve the problem. The rest of lines shold be of the form

```
& (text of line) \\
```

if you are accepting aligning to the left, of course.

Comment: My bloody head hurts.